# Lystrosaurus was the largest creature on land in the early Triassic, why did they need burrows?

Tags: palaeontology, biogeography

Lystrosaurus was the largest creature on land in the early Triassic, why did they need burrows? What were they hiding from?

(less seriously, why were they so ugly?)

Comment: Maybe they were hiding from the weather?  E.g. bears are pretty big, but they find places to hibernate in the winter.  Or perhaps they inherited the burrowing habit from a smaller ancestor?  As for their looks, it's in the eye of the beholder.  I think they're kinda cute :-)